# SailsJs waterline adapter for couchbase

Tags: sails.js, couchbase, waterline

Just wondering i tried to search high and low for this but cant find anything that works with the new couchbase sdk for node. Anyone know if such adapter exist?

If not i guess i have to roll my own..

Answer (score 1):

There is no official adapter for Couchbase recognized by sails for the moment. However, there is one adapter which is almost finished but combine Couchbase and ElasticSearch which is available on npmjs.org.
https://www.npmjs.com/package/sails-cbes